# Highcharts custom markers in pie chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to create a chart in which the marker symbol/image like this [pie example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ffmb.jpg).

I tried searching for it in the highcharts API and googled it as well. Couldn't find a solution.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So what's your question? What have you tried, and what specifically is not working in your implementation?

Comment: I think that you can achieve similar chart using chart.renderer methods. Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/zsf05d44/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński great. Thanks for your response!